# What does it mean "as weird as the way it takes Chicago"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I'm watching Top Gear, a TV series about vehicle. There's a scene when the driver is driving fast and listening to "ABBA in Spanish" at the same time. And the presenter describes this as "as weird as the way it takes Chicago, strangely calm that." Can you explain this phrase in simple English for me please?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me, either. Are you sure this is what they really said.

Comment: It sounds as if it might be a response which builds upon something earlier in the dialogue, perhaps like a comparison to something just mentioned. Would you please give us more context, if you are able?

Comment: This is what subtitled in the video. Here's the link to the [video] (https://youtu.be/rJaqfk2MUxk?t=588). Thank you.

Comment: @Tonepoet in the scene, the presenter is commenting on a driver driving a car like in a F1 race. Previously he just mentions about the driver's cutting a corner that is so good and with "no dramas". Beside that I don't see anything that seems to relate. Here's the script from beginning of the scene:
  
 _"Double clutch gearbox shifting seamlessly, going through the first corner, no dramas whatsoever. Stig listening to ABBA in Spanish, very weird. Almost as weird as the way it takes Chicago, strangely calm that..."_
  
Stig is the name of the driver.

Comment: The presenters on TG refer to the Stig as an "it" or a thing, not as a human. So the"it" in the sentence is the Stig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Chicago" is the name of the curve that the car is taking,  maneuvering around, or dealing with. The announcer then mentions the next curve, "Hammerhead."

*Take* 4.8 from [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/take):

> Deal with (a physical obstacle or course) in a specified way:
>
> *he takes the corners with no concern for his own safety*

From the [Top Gear Wikia](http://topgear.wikia.com/wiki/Top_Gear_test_track):

> The start and finish of the track are both placed on the same spot. The drive starts off with a very slight curve, followed by a large and fast left curve into a service road called "Crooner Curves", followed quickly by "Chicago", a long right-hand curve around a tire wall.
>
> Hammerhead
>
> After Chicago, there are three short curves, called "Hammerhead", after which comes a long straight, ending with a right-hand curve,

The phrase *as weird as* makes a comparison between listening to ABBA in Spanish and the way the driver takes or deals with the curve called Chicago. The use of the comparison allows the presenter to move or segue from one topic to the next in a seamless fashion.

Comment: Beat me to it...  Here's a track diagram though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Gear_test_track#/media/File:TG_Test_Track.PNG